# Unable to use perf to find L3 Cache miss rate

Tags: cache, perf, perf-event

I am trying to get the L3 cache miss rate when I try to use perf. The following is the command I run:

```
perf stat -e instructions,LLC-load-misses,LLC-loads ./program <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>
```

Then I get the following output:

```
   667,922,092,353      instructions                                                
   <not supported>      LLC-load-misses                                             
   <not supported>      LLC-loads                                                   

      47.619915412 seconds time elapsed

      42.245969000 seconds user
       5.371741000 seconds sys
```

I have already run the following command to install perf:

```
apt-get install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic linux-tools-`uname -r`
```

The following are my system specs:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 
Kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5900x

It also does not work if I run as root

Comment: Does `perf list|grep LLC` show the events as supported on your CPU?

Comment: no it doesn't show anything

Comment: Well, might be some unsupported cpu feature (or disabled because of errata). `perf list cache` shows you the available cache-related counters though.

Comment: Performance events can be divided into two categories: `core and uncore`. Since you receive `<not supported>` as the output of the `perf` command for the LLC-load-misses event, it must be an uncore event.  If an event is classified as uncore, it is accessed differently (using a unit and register id). To use the perf tool correctly, consult the kernel documentation and technical reference manual for AMD Ryzen.